# how to convert looping into function

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:
score

```
    grade  score
0     A      90
1     B      80
2     C      70
3     D      60
```

students

```
    name   grades
0   Adam   [A, B, A, F]
1   Jane   [C, B, A, F]
```

I would like to add a new column which contains the score of each grade as the following:

```
grades_list = []
for student in students['grades']:
     grades_list2 = []
     for grade in student:
          try:
               grades_list2.append(score.loc[score['grade'] == grade, 'score'].iloc[0])
          except:
               grades_list2.append(0)
     grades_list.append(grades_list2)

students['score'] = pd.DataFrame({'score': grades_list})
```

How can I create a function that can do this more efficiently?

Comment: Efficiency is not determined by whether or not you do this in a function!

Comment: Turning this into a function will not change the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :

```
dic=dict(zip(score.grades,score.score))
students['score']=students['grades'].apply(lambda row : [dic[sub] for sub in row])
```

It uses pandas functions instead of loop over dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas [apply](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-apply/) to efficiently process each row of Pandas series (i.e. faster than Python for loop)

**Code**

```
def convert_grades(grades):
  ' Convert list of letter grades to numbers '
  # Convert string list to list (e.g. "[A, B]" -> ["A", "B"])
  grades = grades[1:-1].split(',')

  # Map grades with default of 0 for grades not in dictionary
  return [map_grades.get(g.strip(), 0) for g in grades]

# Create dictionary to map grades to numbers using DataFrame columns
# grade and score of df_grades
map_grades = df_grades.set_index('grade').to_dict()['score']

# Use apply which applies function convert_grades to the grades column
students['score'] = students['grades'].apply(convert_grades)
```

**With**

df_grades

```
  grade  score
0     A     90
1     B     80
2     C     70
3     D     60
```

students

```
  name        grades
0  Adam  [A, B, A, F]
1  Jane  [C, B, A, F]
```

**Result**

```
  name        grades            score
0  Adam  [A, B, A, F]  [90, 80, 90, 0]
1  Jane  [C, B, A, F]  [70, 80, 90, 0]
```